# Datepicker for Bootstrap: Embedded / inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I like very much datepicker for Bootstrap by Eternicode:
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

I use his form to generate what i want to insert in my site: the calendar in the format Embedded/inline.

http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=embedded&format=dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy&weekStart=&startDate=now&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

As Jquery it is generated this code:

```
$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "now"
});
```

But as HTML it is generated only this code:

```
<div></div>
```

What HTML i have to put inside to have the calendar in Embedded/inline style?
Thank you!

Comment: can you show me your code? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$('#sandbox-container').datepicker` for input field but not for `Div`

if you look at the [demo here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/), you will see its an input

Comment: i would like the demo for the embedded/inline type.
The input field i had already tried and it works, but what i actually need is the calendar with TYPE: embedded/line. 
But when i generate it, using that form, no HTML is returned except <div></div>

Comment: Right now i have just the JQuery code:
      $('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "now"
}); 

And no html..

Comment: Oh man! There was the mistake i just change $('#calendar') and call <div id="calendar">. And now it works smoothly!

Answer (score 3):

The actual fix is to give your Div and ID and reuse this id in your datepicker code:

JS:

```
$('#sandbox-container').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "now"
});
```

html:

```
<div id="sandbox-container"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To put inside to have the calendar in Embedded/inline style. The html will be:`<div id='sandbox-container'><div></div></div>`